# MVC - Validating Id field in new records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a custom login for MVC. In my Account controller I have two actions:

- Index (I post here when user registers)
- Login

The Index action is taking `MemberModel` as argument and Login is taking `LoginModel`. My problem is I can not validate MemberModel in Index because of error "Id field is required".

I did a little research and added `[Bind(Exclude="Id")]` to my code. So, right now my signature is looking like this:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Exclude="Id")]MemberModel model)
```

My problem is that I cannot post to this method since I added [Bind(Exclude="Id")] part to the signature. For some reason all post requests are going to the Login action.

And my view is looking like

```
@if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) { 
    using (@Html.BeginForm("Index","Account")) { 
    @Html.ValidationMessage("MailError")

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

    <br />

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname)

    <br />

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)

    <br />

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)

    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    }
}
```

Comment: why not just remove the Id Hidden Field?

Comment: @pollirrata looks like that's it. Please post as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```